# Is it possible to send automated messages with Signal Messenger?

Tags: messaging

I would like to send periodic, automated messages to a preset list of my Singal contacts. Groups would work if there were a way to Bcc group members such that other groups members couldn’t see each other. I’m wondering if there’s some kind of API or other interface for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It has been requested multiple times but it seems that nothing has come of it:

- [Feature: send schedule](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/issues/253)
- [Add scheduling of text messages for Android](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/issues/2109)

The latest messages in [this thread](https://community.signalusers.org/t/feature-scheduled-send-of-messages/2568/28) on the official site do seem to hint that it's a possible addition in the future. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no official way to send automated messages to Signal.

But there is an app for sending automatic replies. It can also be connected to your web server:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tkstudio.autoresponderforsignal